# Need advise on creation of account

Tags: accounts, eosio-code

I am working on ICO based on eosio so what actually i need to do is i want to make a system in which all users come to signup and system generate a key pair for them and give them key and registered account.
So,My questions are as below

1)Can we create an account(i will call it as master account)which is 
  having ram and gives all the user their ram,cpu and net is this 
  possible?

2)Is there any way that if user do transaction from their key and ram,cpu 
  and net can be used of master account?

3)Is there any other way that may be more feasible for ico ?

I know that if we give users to handle their own account then it will 
  make trouble for them to handle all the account resource. Suggestions 
  are admired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Can we create an account(i will call it as master account)which is having ram and gives all the user their ram,cpu and net is this possible?

Yes, you can use:

```
$ cleos system newaccount <master-account> <new-account>  --stake-net "<amount> EOS" --stake-cpu "<amount> EOS"  --buy-ram-bytes <amount>
```

This would create a new account where the NET and CPU is delegated based on staked EOS from the master account, and the RAM is bought from the master account as well.

> 2) Is there any way that if user do transaction from their key and ram,cpu and net can be used of master account?

They can use the resources your staked/purchased for them. However, if they add more NET/CPU/RAM than the resources you have already provided for them, then they'll use those new resources for their activities. They can't use the NET/CPU of a different account, unless that account explicitly stakes resources for them.

Potentially, this can be automated through a smart contract, where a user could buy more NET/CPU by making a request to your contract (instead of requesting from `eosio.system`), which, in turn, will delegate more CPU/NET for them.

> 3) Is there any other way that may be more feasible for ico ?

BlockOne [announced they'll start creating free account for new users](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/983vvm/dan_confirms_free_accounts_will_be_offered_and/) so you could wait for that depending on your timeline.